# Change file.encoding to show umlauts

Tags: android

I'm showing an about text from a text file with the following code. But I have problems to show german umlauts ä, ü, ö correctly. How can I change or set the encoding?
Androis says:

> public InputStreamReader (InputStream in)  Since: API Level 1
>
> Constructs a new InputStreamReader on the InputStream in. This
>   constructor sets the character converter to the encoding specified in
>   the "file.encoding" property and falls back to ISO 8859_1
>   (ISO-Latin-1) if the property doesn't exist.

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.help); 
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.help_text);
    //tv.setText(readRawTextFile(R.raw.help));
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(readRawTextFile(R.raw.help)));
}

public static String readRawTextFile(int id) {
    InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(in);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while (( line = buf.readLine()) != null) 
            text.append(line);
        //text.append("<br>" );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to specify the charset being used in the text file during the InputStreamReader creation with:

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset);
```

You can find available charsets in: [Charset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Good luck.